# Windows Command line echo date command

Tags: windows, command

This might be a basic question but I am having a hard time to find a solution. We have an user in Asia for whom echo %date% returns 08/20/2018 Mon

And same command returns Mon 08/20/2018 in US. I would like to fetch date in both scenarios in a batch file. How would I know if result of date command returns date first or second ( after day information)?

Answer (score 0):

He will simply need to change region settings to US. It's the time format.

Go to region and language settings and change country or region to United States.

Comment: Hi Rick Thanks for your comment. I don't want my script to be dependent on regional settings.We might get new users in both regions and I can't ask everyone to check settings.